# How to have a button call a method programmatically in a class in swift?

Tags: swift, class, func

I want the button to slide off the screen when it's hit, but that part of the code (buttonPressed) isn't working. When the method buttonPressed is inside the class, nothing happens when the button is pressed. Move the method outside of the brackets (to right before viewDidLoad) and the code executes. However, then it slides the entire view as opposed to just the tutorial window. I either need to find a way to make buttonPressed work as a method of the Tutorial class, or find a way to make it refer to the specific instance of "view" that's called in the class.

I'm new to coding and very new to methods, so any help is appreciated!

```
class Tutorial{
    var label = UILabel()
    var view = UIView()
    var button = UIButton()

    init (text: String){
        view = UIView()
        label = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 10, y: 10, width: 180, height: 90))
        button = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 50, y: 110, width: 100, height: 30))
        view.backgroundColor = .white
        view.layer.cornerRadius = 15
        view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        label.textAlignment = .center
        label.text = text
        label.numberOfLines = 10
        label.backgroundColor = .white
        label.textColor = UIColor(red:0.12, green:0.15, blue:0.23, alpha:1.0)
        button.backgroundColor = UIColor(red:0.23, green:0.72, blue:0.44, alpha:1.0)
        button.setTitleColor(.white, for: .normal)
        button.setTitle("Got it!", for: .normal)
        button.layer.cornerRadius = 15
        view.addSubview(label)
        view.addSubview(button)
        button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(buttonPressed), for: UIControlEvents.touchUpInside)
    }
    func setConstraints(height: CGFloat){
        view.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.superview!.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
        view.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.superview!.topAnchor, constant: UIScreen.main.bounds.height-300).isActive = true
        view.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 200).isActive = true
        view.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: height).isActive = true
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, delay: 0.2, options: [], animations: {
            self.view.center.x -= UIScreen.main.bounds.width
        })
    }
    @objc func buttonPressed(){
        print("Pressed")
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, delay: 0.0, options: [], animations: {
            self.view.center.x -= UIScreen.main.bounds.width
        },
                       completion: { (finished: Bool) in
                        self.view.isHidden = true
        })
    }
}
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let tutorial1 = Tutorial(text: "Click and hold to see the anatomy overlay")
        self.view.addSubview(tutorial1.view)
        tutorial1.setConstraints(height: 150)
```

Answer (score -1):

Try using Interface Builder Constants. Here is the Apple Documentation. https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/constants/interface_builder_constants?language=objc
make an IBOutlet and an IBAction for your button.

Comment: I know how to make the function and programming work in IB, however I'm going to add multiple tutorials and would prefer to do it programmatically.